# Get the value from a variable

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm using PyQt4 to make an interface for a project that I'm working on, and I want to remove tab widget which I have and replace it with another. Here's what my remove function looks like:

```
def remove(self):
    self.removeTab(0)
    self.addTab(Tabs.Example(self.nao, self.parent), "Example")
#END remove
```

Now, I have multiple tabs, somewhere around 5-6, and more will be added later. I don't want to make a method for removing and adding each tab, ie:

```
def remove1
    removeTab
    addTabExample1

def remove2
    removeTab
    addTabExample2
```

So I figured I would pass a name variable, and did this:

```
def remove(self, name):
    self.removeTab(0)
    self.addTab(Tabs.name(self.nao, self.parent), name)
```

However, this doesn't work as there's no class in Tabs called name. So I'm wondering how I should do this, and is there an easy way of getting the value from a variable? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def remove(self, tabToAdd, name):
    self.removeTab(0)
    self.addTab(tabToAdd, "%s" %(name))
```

where you need to define `tabToAdd` and `name` before calling `remove()`

```
tabToAdd  = Tabs.nameOfYourTab(self.nao, self.parent) 
name = "string name of your tab"
```

that way you pass widget you want to add and name that is string.